# Is it possible to have my class adhere to this protocol that seems to require a struct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, messagekit

I'm using [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit), and it requires that you have model objects that adopt the protocol `MessageType`. Most of the examples involves structs following the protocol but unfortunately I'm using a third party API library to interact with a site's API, and they have all their models as classes (in Objective-C).

So when I try to adopt the protocol with `extension ServerMessage: MessageType` I get the error

> Inheritance from non-protocol type

How can I make it work with my Objective-C class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any protocol that works with a `struct` is bound to work with a `class`. The limitation is the other way around. It is hard to provide an answer without a code snippet, but I do not see why it should not work.

```swift
@objc class ServerMessage: NSObject {

}

protocol MessageType {
    var sender: Any { get }
}

extension ServerMessage: MessageType {
    var sender: Any { return () }
}
```

This dummy code does not provide any errors. Maybe you had a typo somewhere?